# Flutter Set Marker Size

Tags: javascript, flutter

I want a Google Maps marker to be on a fixed size on a certain zoom level, like in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/bryan_weaver/4rxqQ/

Can I provide this on google maps in Flutter

```
 BitmapDescriptor markerbitmap = await BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
      const ImageConfiguration(size: Size(1,1000)),
      "lib/assets/images/lol.png",
 );


  markers.add(
    Marker( //add start location marker

    draggable: false,
        anchor: const Offset(0.5, 0.9),
      markerId: MarkerId(startLocation.toString()),
      position: startLocation, //position of marker
      infoWindow: const InfoWindow( //popup info 
        title: 'Starting Point ',
        snippet: 'Start Marker',
      ),
      
      icon: markerbitmap,//Icon for Marker
    )
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a package in flutter pub dev. It name is  Google maps flutter. I think you can use this package.

Comment: please check the [SO Guidelines for answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Just a gentle help for future answers, check the link out.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I already added package Flutter Google Maps but i could not solve this problem because it is not enough to fix my problem. Could you give me another solution about Marker.

Answer (score 0):

YOU can set icon in center using Stack Widget

Comment: Did you mean, i have to wrap in Stack Widget "icon: markerbitmap"

Comment: i used this package for Google Map :google_maps_flutter

Comment: I'm using to package but i could not find any solutions about my problem.Unfortunately, i can't use Stack Widget in Marker widget. If you possible to write answer in Dart i will so grateful

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).